# Divergence of a dot product of tensor and vector

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors, classical-mechanics

Hei, I am trying to derive energy equation from Navier-Stokes equation and I come across this:
$$\nabla.(\sigma.v)=(\nabla.\sigma).v +\sigma:\nabla v$$
$\sigma $ is the stress tensor

V :is the velocity vector

Could anyone thankfully explain this and if that is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider an orthonormal basis of the euclidean space. The divergence reads
\begin{aligned}
\nabla\cdot (\sigma\cdot v) &= (\sigma_{ij} v_j)_{,i} \\ &= \sigma_{ij,i} v_j + \sigma_{ij} v_{j,i} \\
&= \sigma_{ji,i} v_j + \sigma_{ji} v_{j,i} \\
&= (\nabla\cdot\sigma)\cdot v + \sigma : \nabla v
\end{aligned}
using Einstein notation and the symmetry of the stress tensor.

Comment: Why the switch the indexes of sigma from $\sigma_{ij,i}$ to $\sigma_{ji,i}$?

Comment: @Olumide the stress tensor is symmetric, therefore we can switch those indices